# How to disable screen update in long running word macro?

Tags: vba, ms-word

I've got a word 2013 macro which is taking quite some time to finish.

The macro is reformatting the document and the Screen keeps updating while the macro is running, which I guess is where word spends most of it's time.

How can I disable screen updating in word in a macro and refresh it when the macro is finished?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try with adding this line at the beginning of your code:

```
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
```

and this at the end:

```
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
```

If this doesn't help you need to add more information and possibly post your code.

Comment: Does work nicely! The macro still is slow, but these are large documents so this should not surprise - thanks!